# Fridge is cold after manual defrosting, but then warms

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Westinghouse Mastermind refrigerator. The fridge compartment is not cold. If I switch the fridge off overnight, and turn it back on in the morning, it is cold again. After a couple of weeks, it stops being cold again.

Can you suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Why do you think this isn't a problem with the defroster? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Does water come out of it while it is switched off?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I actually think it is a problem with the defroster. If it is, I would like to know if it is worth repairing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton water collects in a collection bowl on top of the compressor. It is almost overflowing in the morning.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already identified there's a problem with the automatic defrost function.

To dive deeper into that problem you could test whether the automatic control is working or you could test whether the defrost heating element is working. The latter is easier to test, and one might argue it is also more likely to fail.

Remove power from the appliance, expose the defrost heating element, and disconnect at least one of the two wires going into the element. Measure its resistance. I don't know anything specific about your appliance, but based on general experience, I'd expect a working defrost heater element to have a resistance under 100 ohms, and probably even less than 50 ohms. If you measure much over 100, and certainly if it measures open circuit, then the element itself has failed.